# Delete all child nodes of selected node for jsTree in Django

Tags: javascript, django, jstree

I am trying to delete nodes in my jsTree, but am running into the issue that when the page is refreshed, the child nodes of the deleted node are still saved but no longer have a parent and the tree won't load and returns an error as a result.

I need a way to delete all of the child nodes associated with the selected node when the selected node is deleted so that I don't get this error.

Currently I have figured out how to delete the children one level below the selected node being deleted, but can't figure out how to delete multiple tiers of child nodes.

Here's my javascript, if this is not sufficient to help me solve the problem, let me know and I will post more relevant code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree_demo').jstree({
            "core" : {
                "animation" : 0,
                "check_callback" : true,
                "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
                'data' : {
                  "url" : "/snippets/",
                  "success": function(data){
                     series = data;
            },
                  "dataType" : "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
                }
            },

            "plugins" : [ "contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "state", "types", "wholerow" ]
        });
});

function demo_delete() {
    var ref = $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true),
        //actual node being deleted
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    // deletes one tier below selected
    selNode = ref.get_node(sel);
    ref.delete_node(selNode.children)
    //deletes selected
    ref.delete_node(sel);

};

$('#jstree_demo').on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    console.log('something was deleted')
    var new_node = {
        'id': data.node.id,
        'parent': data.node.parent,
        'text': data.node.text
    }
    var somethingElse = JSON.stringify(new_node);

    $.ajax({
      url:'/snippets/' + data.node.id,
      type:"DELETE",
      contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType:"json",

    })
})
```

Thank you for your help. If there is a clarification issue, let me know and I will respond promptly.

Edit:
Model:

```
from django.db import models
class StoringJSON(models.Model):
  id = models.TextField(primary_key='true', default='1')
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=u'Parent', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
  text = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Node')
```

View:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def tree_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a tree instance.
    """
    try:
        tree = StoringJSON.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except StoringJSON.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = TreeSerializer(tree)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TreeSerializer(tree, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        tree.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I think I might have to instantiate the first object in order to get it started but Im not sure how to.

Comment: Did you use foreign keys for model to set parent? Something like
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'Parent node')

If you create like that, then when parent node deleted, all related nodes will be deleted too

Comment: When I try to use your example I get an error for assigning the parent
ValueError: Cannot assign "'#'": "StoringJSON.parent" must be a "StoringJSON" instance.

Comment: can you show your model and your delete view in django?